# imacro search for word in button and click it

Tags: imacros

I have this with imacro

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://mycoinads.com/surfbtc.php?btcaddress=19f83eqk1GpgjtTjQeMEEwMrgZtUn29a7S
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 35
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:*<SP>Click<SP>here<SP>to
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:click<SP>here<SP>for<SP>the<SP>next<SP>ad
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 35
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:collectcredits.php?ad=1624&btcaddress=19f83eqk1GpgjtTjQeMEEwMrgZtUn29a7S&hash=6260c98d8333bbb582fa738a46d62d62&id= ATTR=*
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:click<SP>here<SP>for<SP>the<SP>next<SP>ad
```

But when it needs to press the button Click here to it gives this error
RuntimeError:

> element SPAN specified by TXT:*Clickhereto was not found, line 5 (Error code: -921)

Hope someone can help
So that it find the text and clicks it

Answer (score 0):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=TXT:"Your text here"
```

Try here.